# Adversarial learning gradient derivation

Tags: self-study, neural-networks, deep-learning, proof, conv-neural-network

I'm working through Convolutional Neural Network [paper here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.6572v3.pdf) on adversarial learning and I'm having trouble with the derivative proof of adversarial logistic regression. The correct answer presented (on page 4) is:

$$E_{x,y~p_{data}}\zeta(y(\epsilon||w||_1-w^Tx-b))$$

However, my derivation, based on the loss function from page three gives the sign of the gradient as $\newcommand{\sign}{{\rm sign}} -\sign(y(W^T))$ rather than $-\sign(W)$. I've been going through my math for the past two hours and if anyone could shed any insight, that would be really helpful. I've written out my logic below.

\begin{align}
E_{x,y~p_{data}}\zeta(-y(w^Tx-b))  \\
\zeta(z) &= \log(1 + \exp(z))  \\[5pt]
\frac{\partial{E_{xy}}}{\partial{x}} &= \partial x(\frac{1}{1+e^{-y(w^Tx+b)}})  \\[5pt]
&=\frac{e^{-y(w^Tx+b)}}{1+e^{-y(w^Tx+b)}}\partial x (-y(w^Tx+b))  \\[5pt]
&=\frac{e^{-y(w^Tx+b)}}{1+e^{-y(w^Tx+b)}}(-yw^T)  \\[5pt]
\sign\bigg(\frac{\partial{E_{xy}}}{\partial{x}}\bigg)&=-\sign(yw^T)
\end{align}

Comment: Welcome to the site. I have edited the $\LaTeX$, please ensure it still says what you want it to. Also, you should probably add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: yes, I think it should depend on $y$.